# ES6 generators with non-blocking events

Tags: node.js, events, iterator, ecmascript-6, generator

I am trying to wrap some ES6 generators around an mssql library for node. The mssql library supports streaming, however it does so by issuing events. This is similar to the non-blocking services that come with Node.

The problem I am having is how to continue the generator in the context of an event handler. For example:

```
class myClass {
  // ...

  *myGenerator(querystring) {
     mssql.connect(this.config)
          .then(() => {
             let request = new mysql.Request();
             request.stream = true;
             request.query(querystring);

             request.on('row', row => {
               yield row; // DOH!
             });

             request.on('error', err => {
               throw err;
             });

             request.on('done', affected => {
               return affected; // DOH!
             });
          });
   }
}
```

Is it even possible to convert an event-based non-blocking streaming API into an iterator generator here? Or is that simply out of context for the current specification in ES6?

Comment: [Async iterators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration) is a stage 3 proposal at the moment. You can use [Babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-generator-functions/) to use it today.

Comment: Your `then` callback is not a generator function, so you are not allowed to use `yield` inside that function. I would suggest using [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) for such use cases.

Comment: Felix...I checked that spec, and I am honestly not sure how Async iterators solve the problem at hand. I need to yield from a nested scope...two, actually, as @DevDig pointed out. How are the Async iterators any different than regular iterators in that particular use case? I don't think I could `yield async` any more from within my `request.on` handlers  than I can `yield`...